# Best way to handle save form process (insert vs update) with ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have been looking for a good way to handle insert vs update process in my forms on the front end forms. There is two possible scenarios, one is where users want to enter new data and save that record. The other option is to update existing record. I have one universal function that handles this processes in the past. It was based on unique id that was passed after insert/update was completed on the back end. Now I'm looking for something that would use string `Insert` or `Update` and pass that with the rest of my form data. Here is example of what I'm talking about:

```js
$('#frmSave').on('submit', submitFrm);
function submitFrm(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevnts default form submit.
    
    var frmObject = $(this),
        frmMessage = $(this).find(".message-submit"),
        keyObj = $("#frmSave_process"),
        formData = frmObject.serialize();
    
    if(formData){  
        frmObject.find(':submit').prop('disabled', true); // Disable submit button
        
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'Components/Functions.cfc?method=saveData',
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'json'
        }).done(function(obj){
            if(obj.STATUS === 200){
                  //Here I would need to change parameter hidden value process. So if user decideds to submit the form again, update process should be executed.
   frmMessage.show().addClass(obj.CLASS).html(obj.MESSAGE).delay(7000).fadeOut('slow').queue(function({
                    $(this).removeClass(obj.CLASS).dequeue();
                    frmObject.find(':submit').prop('disabled', false);
                }); 
            }else{
                frmMessage.show().addClass(obj.CLASS).html(obj.MESSAGE).delay(7000).fadeOut('slow').queue(function(){
                    $(this).removeClass(obj.CLASS).dequeue();
                    frmObject.find(':submit').prop('disabled', false); 
                }); 
            }  
        }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('Error: '+errorThrown);
        });
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<form name="frmSave" id="frmSave">
  <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="frmSave_process" id="frmSave_process">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="status"><span class="label label-primary">Status:</span></label>
    <select class="form-control" name="frm_status" id="frm_status" required>
      <option value="0">Inactive</option>
      <option value="1">Active</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="name"><span class="label label-primary">Name:</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="frm_name" id="frm_name" maxlength="50" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9 ][A-Za-z0-9 ]{0,50}$" title="Name allows alphanumeric characters and space - no other special characters" required>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <button type="submit" name="frm_submit" id="frm_submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <div id="frm_message" class="alert message-submit"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Is there a good way to handle this with JavaScript and JQuery to decide insert vs update process?

Comment: No. Make this decision server-side.  What if the user has the form open in two browser windows, and tries to "insert" it twice?

Comment: @WillardSolutions I think they will insert two records. If they are same records they will then update existing one, correct?

Comment: Depends on what you're doing in backend code. My point is that you can't rely on a client-side indicator to determine whether an entry should be inserted or updated. Your CFC will need to validate that determination.

Comment: Well based on the client side code I'm either will have an ajax call to insert or update function. If they try to mess with the code and call update instead of an insert they will get an error since there are SQL database restrictions in each of my tables. I hope this make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to create different routes on server for insert & update actions, and on the front end pass different route as a **data-url** attribute to the form based on the case when a) user creates new record b) user updates the existing one record.

Then you may get that url for ajax call like this `$('#form').attr("data-url")`

Doing this way, it will be a way more flexible to change old or add new logic to those actions in the future, because neither of the actions will be dependent on each other changes.

Comment: Pawel, are you thinking about two different functions on the back end or use different `url` for each or I miss understood your answer?

Comment: Hope I can explain this moment better - I suggested to use two different `urls` for the form, where from each `url` you are calling  different function. So if the user creates new record - url will be something like `/create` from where you call `function create()...`, if the user updates existing record, url is `/update` from where you call `function update()...`